# Unity - Get the reference to canvas elements

Tags: c#, canvas, unity-game-engine

all of my GUI elements of the canvas got a tag. For example, my health bar got the tag "HealthBar". In the script, I don't want to write a public variable, I want to find these elements automatically by finding the tag.

So when I try to reference them, how can I search for them? They are no GameObjects.

My current state:

```
private Image experienceBar; // The XP bar

private void Start()
{
    GameObject playerUI = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("PlayerUI"); // The canvas
    experienceBar = playerUI. ?; // Find the UI element by tag
}
```

I don't know, how to get the ui elements tag there.

Thanks for help.

Comment: As a side note, it's WAY better to always use a public or serialized private field, since the Find methods are slow as hell.

Answer (score 1):

```
experienceBar = playerUI.Find("ExperienceBar").getComponent<Image>();
```

Where the "ExperienceBar" is the experience bar prefab's name.

Better yet if your PlayerUI has a SerializedField for the experience bar which you can fill within the editor with the experience bar. Thus you won't need to "Find" it.

```
[SerializeField]
private Image experienceBar;
```

Comment: Yeah this is the way I already got, with SerializeField, but I tried to find a nice way to fill it by Script :)

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there!  Essentially now you have the gameobject of that UI element, if you want to access a UI element then you want to do a `GetComponent` call.  In your case you do it like:

```
experienceBar = playerUI.Find(ObjectName).GetComponent<Image>();
```

All your doing is telling the system to return that component that is attached to your gameobject, if there isn't a component that matches the type in the `<...>` it'll return null.  Also note the object name matches the name of your object (i.e. "ExperienceBar" or whatever)

Comment: Ye, thanks, but sadly I already know this. But I have on my canvas more than one Image. HealthBar, ExperienceBar, etc. so how can I use the bars tag to get the RIGHT bar. GetComponent<> would just return any bar :/

Comment: Okay then do a find then GetComponent